# ASP.NET MVC Authentication by Permission (or Activity or Operation) rather than by Role

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, security, authentication

ASP.NET MVC offers the possibility to secure your controllers and their methods by decorating them with attributes like `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrators, Content Editor")]`.

I would like to use this mechanism, but with a check on Permissions rather than on Roles.
This is a better design : A user has one or more role(s) and each role has a permission set. The security checks are then done on permissions and it is easier to add a new role with specific permissions.

I would like to use the standard SQL Role provider. So the only solution I've found so far is to use everything provided by Microsoft, but also rather use the normal 'Roles' as Permissions. Then I would have to create a custom table (and UI) to handle the associations between real Roles (custom table) and the Microsoft 'Roles' (used rather as permissions).

Is there any better way of doing what I need?

Thanks!

Comment: I've done something like the solution you describe, using a custom RoleProvider which uses permissions as roles, and a custom UI to manage the mapping of roles to permissions.

Comment: Hi @Joe, well, I'd be interested to see that, if you don't mind :)

Comment: Granular permissions can be implemented using the authorize attribute if you just create new roles like "CanEditForm", but will result in a lot of duplicate code unless you implement a custom RoleProvider of some sort